# What does a blinking Main LED on my ACCL mean?

Tags: electrical

I have this [Havells ACCL](https://www.havells.com/en/consumer/switchgear/energy-saver/automatic-source-changeover-with-current-limiter/premium-spn-accl-with-gen-start-stop.html#gref) installed that helps automatically switch between the main supply and the generator.

It was installed 5-6 years back and I have lost the original packing etc. Even the product spec I found online via their Whatsapp bot doesn't have any pertinent info. As far as I know, it doesn't have a battery. It has 4 indicator LEDs viz. Mains, Gen, Load, Overload.

Since yesterday all the lights/appliances connected to the changeover have stopped working. I have tried the reset button a couple of times and even switched the MCB off/on a couple of times however nothing's working. The Mains LED blinks continuously and the other 3 are off. I am unable to understand if the ACCL has gone bad and needs replacing or whether there is something else that I can try to restore the power supply.

Comment: First stop should be the instructions that came with the appliance.

Comment: This is like saying I have a blinking light on my car! What model, brand will be helpful. How long has it been in and does it have a battery?

Comment: ACCL = automatic transfer switch, or what is an ACCL?

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more specific. Here's a link to the product I am referring to - https://www.havells.com/en/consumer/switchgear/energy-saver/automatic-source-changeover-with-current-limiter/premium-spn-accl-with-gen-start-stop.html#gref

It was installed 5-6 years back and I have lost the original packing etc. Even the product spec I found online via their Whatsapp bot doesnt have any pertinent info. As far as I know, it doesn't have a battery.

Comment: Contact company and ask. You might find a user manual on their website with a diagnostics section.